# Trouble with using class types within other classes

Tags: c++, class, c-preprocessor

I have absolutely no idea what's going on. I've been looking up explanations for the weirdness going on here but it seems my situation is in some ways unique. I imagined it was the order in which I include my header files in each of my files, but to no avail, I have not found a combination that seems to be the solution.

The exact error I seem to be getting is "log does not name a type" when declaring `LogArray[maxLength]`.

One of my classes, class logmgmt:

```
class logmgmt
{
private:
static const int maxLength = 500;
log LogArray[maxLength];
int length;

public:
void fillLogs(int index, int iD, std::string date, double startTime, double endTime);
void displayThisLog(int index);
void setLength(int length);

};
```

Pre-processor directives within logmgmt.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#include "log.h"
#include "Logmgmt.h"
```

And directives within main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#include "employee.h"
#include "log.h"
#include "employeemgmt.h"
#include "Logmgmt.h"
```

Comment: `log` is a builtin function in `<cmath>` so naming a user-defined type 'log' is an invitation to disaster.  It's also not defined anywhere in your own code (that you've shown).  `log` needs to be renamed and defined.

Comment: Doing `using namespace std;` before your custom headers are included can surprise you some time too.

Comment: As others have noted - your naming choice is poor. But, you've also not shown us your declaration of `log`, and how it is used in regards to `logmgmt`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `using namespace std`.

That is polluting the global namespace with **lots** of symbol names that can cause these conflicts.

In your example, the function `std::log` becomes `log`.  So it can no longer name a global type.